# Getting the context in a Thread called by a Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, location, android-context

I have the following piece of code:

```
public class DumpLocationLog extends Thread {
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationHelper loc;
    public void onCreate() {
        loc = new LocationHelper();
        lm = (LocationManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    public void run() {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, loc);
    }
}
```

I want it to be run from a remote service but in the line `lm = (LocationManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` I get a `NullPointerException` error of course, because the `context` is null.

How can I get the context here? `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Thread` would not have any direct access to a `Context` by default; you would have to pass it in. A Thread also does not need an `onCreate` method (which I guess you are calling manually) - I would just change it to a constructor. You can just pass in a Context in the constructor of the Thread:

```
public class DumpLocationLog extends Thread {
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationHelper loc;
    public DumpLocationLog(Context context) {
        loc = new LocationHelper();
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    public void run() {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, loc);
    }
}
```

You would instantiate it with `new DumpLocationLog(this);` if used from inside a `Service` (a Service is a subclass of Context, so `this` works here). You start the thread by calling the `start()` method.

Comment: I have it like that, calling from the service like `new DumpLocationLog().start();` although I already tried with `new DumpLocationLog(getApplicationContext()).start();` or `new DumpLocationLog(getBaseContext()).start();` but none of them worked.

Comment: This is what I tried and worked! `Content context;` and `new DumpLocationLog(context, latString, lngString).start();`

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a valid context through the constructor, or, if your class is an inner class inside a service you could use ServiceClassName.this.getContext()

Comment: I tried to pass the valid context through the constructor but then I get the exception `Can’t create handler inside thread that has not called Looper prepare in Android`. My class is not an inner class, could I make it an inner class? Not sure about this..