# Getting input data from resource wav file in "raw" folder

Tags: java, android, input, io

I have been trying to read a buffer from the bytes of a `wav` file located in the raw folder using `InputStream`.

I think what I don't understand is how to give the correct location of the file. 
the `wav` file in the R resource is an int so I cannot just do:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(R.raw.music);
```

because `int` is not acknowledged for `FileInputStream`.

basically my code is a modified version of something I found:

```
public void read(short[] musicin) {
    try {
        // Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data back from the saved file.
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("R.raw.music");

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        int buffsize=512;

        // Read the file into the music array.
        int i = 0;

        while (i<buffsize&&dis.available() > 0) {
            musicin[i] = dis.readByte(); 
            i++;
        }

        // Close the input streams.
        dis.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("AudioTrack","Playback Failed");
    }
}
```

So how can I read from the raw folder?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html. Go through this link.

Comment: Kindly format your code before you paste it as a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your activity class

```
Context c;
c=this;
new yourClass(c);
```

In your class

```
 public yourclass(Context context)
 {

InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfilename); 
}
```

Comment: i tried it but now i have an error... "The method getResources() is undefined for the type Wav_File_Reader" –

Comment: getResouces is a method of a Context. So you need to use context. Are you calling this method in a activity class or outside??

Comment: i am calling a class from the activity and the activity uses a thread

Comment: then pass the activity context to that class.

Comment: thanks, but because i am calling the function inside a thread i cannot use "this"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967221/android-getting-the-context-in-a-thread-called-by-a-service. Go through the link.

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpfull, i have managed to get it (this part of it anyway) working somehow...

Comment: post your answer so someone who has this problem will have a look at your post. If my answer helps accept or upvote it. i have upvoted your question

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

1- add this in the activity before the thread starts:

```
final Context con;
    con=this;
```

2- call the class in the thread

```
new Wav_File_Reader();
```

.
.
.

```
Wav_File_Reader.read(musicin,con);
```

2- modify my class to be static :

```
public static void read(short[] musicin, Context ctx ) {
    try {
    
    //  InputStream is = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);
        
    InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    
    int buffsize=512;
    // Read the file into the music array.
    int i = 0;
    
    short in[]=new short[200000];
    
    //while (dis.available() > 0) {
    //while (i<buffsize&&dis.available() > 0) {
    while (i<200000&&dis.available() > 0) {
        //musicin[i] = dis.readByte(); 
        //in[i]=dis.readByte(); 
        in[i]=dis.readShort();
    i++;
    }

    // Close the input streams.
    dis.close(); 

    } catch (Throwable t) 
    {
    Log.e("AudioTrack","Playback Failed");
    }
    }
```

and I was able to read directly from the `R.raw` folder.

Answer (score 0):

well, InputStream implementation strikes in eye from start, change it to this:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);
```

Comment: i tried it but now i have an error... "The method getResources() is undefined for the type Wav_File_Reader"

Comment: well, in this case `this` is for a `Context` type, so try to change it to:
`InputStream is = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);` if you are calling it inside some Activity-class

Comment: getBaseContext() is also undefined.

Comment: well, then you need to pass context from activity

Comment: have done that and i was able to get this thing to work, thank you very Much you have been very helpfull